# How do you upload an asset via an API or GraphQL

Tags: craft3, assets

Is it possible to upload a new asset via some POST request to craft's API? Or maybe through a graphql mutation?

I noticed in the public schema there is the option for Creating assets within a volume.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

An Asset mutation looks like this:

```graphql
mutation MyMutation(
  $filename: String = "", 
  $url: String = "", 
  $title: String = ""
) {
  save_assets_Asset(
    _file: {filename: $filename, url: $url}
    title: $title
  ) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

With the following variables:

```json
{
  "filename": "image.jpg",
  "url": "https://domain.com/image.jpg",
  "title": "Asset from GQL"
}
```

You would need to change `save_assets_Asset` to match your own volume, of course (`save_assets_VolumeName`).